# editly - Where can I get the return value after a video is created?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, ffmpeg, video-processing

Quick question...

Following along the [README of editly](https://github.com/mifi/editly), I managed to create videos after calling editly like this:

```
    // create video
    editly(editSpec)
        .catch(console.error);
```

Unfortunately, I am using ExpressJS to do this and I need to send back a response when video creation completes.

However, when I tried to extract any value using .then, it returns undefined:

```
    // create video
    editly(editSpec)
    .then(r => {
        console.log(`Is this undefined? Probably yes! r: `, r)
        res.json(r)
    })
        .catch(console.error);
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'd guess that once the `.then` is entered, the video has been created? Have you checked the filesystem then? It may be finished at that point

Comment: Yeah, the .then produces "undefined", which I cannot pin to a response.  I suppose I'll have to resort to just setting a 30 second timeout before rendering the video link in the frontend... kinda meh workaroundy-solution.  Hopefully this can be solved gracefully with some signal but I don't know how to signal success or failure in this editly. :(

Comment: Just because it resolves to `undefined` shouldn't be a problem in itself. The process may well be finished at that point - like I said, check the file system, I bet the video conversion will be finished at that point, so using the `.then` should be just fine

Comment: Can you give example of what you mean check the file system?  I am producing varying sized videos (because I thought of that - checking by file size) which is why I didn't do that, but something tells me you know of a new trick for file system check of completion of the video.

Comment: It looks like `outPath` is in the `editSpec` object, so just check to see if the finished video exists in the `outPath`? Like with `fs.exists`? If it does exist in the `.then`, then you can just use the `.then`

Comment: OMG, I completely forgot about Promise.all!  Derp!  Ok I called editly(editlySpec) within a Promise.all and called res.json in the .then of the Promise.all and viola!  It worked!  Thank you @CertainPerformance for your help.  Your answers made me realize that undefined could just mean I was returning the value too soon.

Comment: Huh? But you only have one Promise, not multiple, right? What does `Promise.all` give you that the plain `.then` doesn't?

Comment: When calling .then, it doesn't wait for some reason.  I tried that.  res.json didn't fire on that for me.  Promise.all may be a bit overkill but it goterdun for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who got stuck on trying to wait for the return value of editly within the context of ExpressJS, here is how I was able to solve this:

```
        // create video via Promise.all
        Promise.all([
            editly(editSpec).catch(e => { return e } )
        ])
        .then(r => {
            console.log(`r: `, r) // still returns undefined but its ok now!  [ undefined ]
            res.json({message: "complete"})
        })
```